# How can I get a person's reports via EWS?

Tags: xml, exchangewebservices

I need to retrieve a person's direct reports from Exchange Web Services, using XML.

I have explored two avenues:

- search for people that have a given manager
- try to access a person's direct reports field

but neither seems to be workable, as i could not find anything that would help in the EWS documentation - for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190895%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

Does anyone know of something that works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Manager property isn't searchable because it's not indexed so a Search wouldn't work. You should be able to get the manager value using Resolve name and specify to return the Contact information eg

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="true" SearchScope="ActiveDirectory" ContactDataShape="AllProperties">
        <m:UnresolvedEntry>da</m:UnresolvedEntry>
      </m:ResolveNames>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

You maybe better using LDAP instead and access the Active Directory or if your using Office365 use the Graph API.

Comment: thanks @Glen - how does one find out what properties are indexed?

Comment: For Directory Interface properties I don't think they are (if you check the underlying AD prop thats a good indication) for store props https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj983804(v=exchg.150).aspx